# Bind "src" attiribute in audio tag within vue code

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, npm-install, vue-router4

try to bind src of audio tag invue code bur does not work ..
Note that object (surah) is api json object ..
this is my code :

```
<audio controls class="audio">
<source :src="'@/data/mp3/' + surah.source" type="audio/mpeg">
<p>عفوًا متصفحك لا يدعم تشغيل الأصوات، قم بتحديثه أو استخدم متصفح آخر.</p>
</audio>
```

rest of code work will (use api) except for this ..

Comment: Pretty sure that the `@` in `@/data/mp3/` references a location alias that your build tool can resolve, but not the browser. If you replace it with the URL to the folder, does it change anything?

Comment: unfortunatly, no .. i tried using "src/data" and "../data" and al posibbes.

Comment: I would assume the webserver does not serve files from src, but from a public or dist folder. Have you checked that the expected URL actually gives you back a file?

Comment: sure i tested  .. any suggested solutions else ?

Comment: Can you provide in your answer a working URL for a file, the content of `surah.source` for that file and the folder structure of your project?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure the surah object is available in component's data
2. Make sure if the mp3 files are stored in a data/mp3 folder
3. Make sure the source property of surah object is a valid string that represents the name of mp3 file (Ex: file_audio.mp3)
4. Try this example:

Template:

```
 <audio controls class="audio">
     <source :src="`@/data/mp3/${surah.source}`" type="audio/mpeg">
     <p>عفوًا متصفحك لا يدعم تشغيل الأصوات، قم بتحديثه أو استخدم متصفح آخر.</p>
 </audio>
```

Script:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
     surah: {
      name: 'يونس',
      Number: 10,
      'Number of Verses': 109,
      'Makki/Madani': 'مكية',
      Theme: 'قصص الأنبياء',
      source: '010.mp3',
     },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: surah is api json file : "Yunus": {
    "name": "يونس",
    "Number": 10,
    "Number of Verses": 109,
    "Makki/Madani": "مكية",
    "Theme": "قصص الأنبياء",
    "source": "010.mp3"
  }

Comment: Thank u for more info, So u can replace surah object in the data method with the API response that u are receiving; This way, u can dynamically update the surah object with the data from the API.